# Puppeteer: share cache between incognito contexts

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, incognito-mode

So I have a "load page, do login" test scenario which I need to run with multiple accounts simultaneously. Since I don't want to share cookies between these sessions I creating an incognito browser context for each. But incognito mode preventing cached files from sharing too which leads to loading speed drops.
So my question is:

- How to use the same cache in different incognito browser contexts
  or
- How to not share cookies in default cache-shared context`s page.

Comment: The only way I found is to use request interceptor ([puppeteer doc](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue)):  
1) Enable it with `page.setRequestInterception(true)`. 
2) Save necessary for caching responses somewhere to local db.  
3) After that responding to these requests with its cached brother with `request.respond`. 
But I hope there is exists more native way of solving this.